# Getting an out of range error iterating through a 2d vector in C++

Tags: c++, stdvector

**EDITED**
For some reason when I run this on Repl.it, I get an out_of_range error 

 All I am trying to do is iterate through a 2d vector **vertically**, and do some other implementations.
This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void matrixElementsSum(vector<vector<int>> matrix) {
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.at(j).size(); j++)
    {
      
      for(i = 0; i<matrix.size(); i++)
      {
        cout << matrix.at(i).at(j) << " ";
        
      }
      
      cout << endl;
      
    }
}


int main() 
{
  vector<vector<int>> vect
    {
        {1, 1, 1, 0},
        {0, 5, 0, 1},
        {2, 1, 3, 10}
    };

   cout << matrixElementsSum(vect);

  return 0;
}
```

And output is

```
1 0 2 
1 5 1 
1 0 3 

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 3) >= this->size() (which is 3)
```

Normally, this error means I am trying to read past the vector size but it is not the case here(at least, that is what I think)

It is hard understanding what is wrong here. I would appreciate any kind of help

**Note**: I don't want to iterate **horizontally**

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < matrix.at(j).size(); j++)` - How do you know that `matrix` has an element with index `j`?

Comment: Every time through the loop you are getting the size of a different vector! So you maybe mean `for (int j = 0; j < matrix.size(); j++)`?

Comment: @Galik that's exactly what I want; I want to iterate through vertically
I realized I may not have been clear enough in my question. I just edited it

Comment: @DanielLangr I'm not sure what your question is, but if it's what I'm thinking, the elements are passed from the main function as I want so I can tell there's an element at ```j```.  They print out fine, except when ```j = 3``` as you can see

Comment: I learned the hard way not to use i and j for row and column indices, but use *row* and *column* instead. This way you understand much better what is going on!

Comment: j is the column number. You can't take j-th row to use its size. Otherwise you have a problem when the number of columns is higher than rows. U.W. is right, you would see this if you used `row` and `column` as variable names.

Comment: `I don't want to iterate horizontally` Please explain what does it mean. Vectors have no notation of "horizontal" or "vertical". Iterate in what way exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each vector has the same length, it's enough to just save the size, assuming there is at least one element.

```
void blabla(vector<vector<int>> matrix) {
    if (matrix.size() == 0) return;
    const size_t jmax = matrix.front().size();
    for (size_t j = 0; j < jmax; j++)
      for(size_t i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
           cout << matrix.at(i).at(j) << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The conditions in 2 loops must be exchanged:

```
void matrixElementsSum(vector<vector<int>> matrix) {
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int nRow = matrix.size();
    int nCol = matrix[0].size();
    for (int j = 0; j < nCol; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < nRow; i++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

The code has been updated to be more self explanatory. To find the number of columns, you don't need to check the number of elements (size) in each row; only first row is enough. The code is breaking when number of columns are more than number of rows and after you go beyond that `matrix[j]` does not exists because it is not a square matrix and that is why `matrix[j].size();` fails.

Comment: Note that `size()` function in vector class returns `size_t` but `i` and `j`'s being compared as signed integers, it yields a compilation warning.

Comment: I think I wasn't clearly enough with my question (I have edited it)
I actually want to iterate through vertically

Comment: @EmmanuelIdun I have updated the answer for the updates in question.

Answer (score 0):

As [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65661552/getting-an-out-of-range-error-iterating-through-a-2d-vector-in-c#comment116092598_65661552) in the comments by [Daniel Langr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/580083/daniel-langr):

> `for (int j = 0; j < matrix.at(j).size(); j++)` - How do you know that `matrix` has an element with index `j`?

It would be better to limit the outer loop to the (previously calculated) size of the longest row and check if the particular element in the inner loop exists before trying to access it.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>      // std::setw
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void matrixElementsSum(std::vector<std::vector<int>> const& matrix, int width)
{ //                                                 ^^^^^^   
    
    auto const longest_row{
        std::max_element( matrix.cbegin(), matrix.cend()
                        , [](auto const& a, auto const& b) {
                              return a.size() < b.size();
    } )};

    auto const max_columns{ longest_row != matrix.cend() ? longest_row->size() : 0 };
    
    for ( size_t col{}; col < max_columns; ++col )
    {
        for( auto const& row : matrix )
        {
            if ( col < row.size() )
                std::cout << std::setw(width) << row[col];
            else
                std::cout << std::setw(width) << "";   
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vect{
        {1, 1, 1, 0},
        {0, 5, 0, 1},
        {2, 1, 3, 10}
    };

//    std::cout << matrixElementsSum(vect);
//                 ^ It's a function returning void, how could this compile?

    matrixElementsSum(vect, 3);

    return 0;
}
```